# Set Builder Notation For Positive Integers Divisible By 5

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question that asks to use set builder notation for positive integers divisible by 5. Would this be the correct way writing it?

$\{x|x \in \mathbb Z, x>0, x \ is \ divisible \ by \ 5\}$

OR would it be written like this?

$\{x|x \in \mathbb Z, x>0, x \ = \ x/5 \}$

Comment: The 1st one of courge.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but just needed to know if the second option was also possible.

Comment: Don't use the second. The only solution to $x=x/5$ is of course $0$. You could introduce another variable and say that it too is an element of the natural numbers, but that's a bit much. I personally think a modular equivalence is exactly what you're looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, the first. If you wanted to be less "wordy", you could write $x \equiv 0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 5)$ instead of $x\ \mathrm{is \ divisible \ by \ }5$.

The second set you described would be empty, as the only $x$ satisfying $x = x/5$ is $x=0$, which is of course excluded by $x>0$. You could, however, rewrite that condition as $x/5 \in \mathbb{Z}$, which would describe the set you're after - again, just another way of writing it.

Comment: So, there's really more than one way of writing it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer too.

Comment: In this case, yeah. The $x \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ b)$ notation (which comes from modular arithmetic) literally means "$x$ has a remainder of $0$ when divided by $b$", but it's only really valid to use if $x$ and $b$ are integers to begin with. $x/b \in \mathbb{Z}$ literally means "$x/b$ is an integer", and in general more versatile - if you wanted all the integer multiples of $1/2$, you could use the condition $2x \in \mathbb{Z}$, but you couldn't use the modular arithmetic notation because $1/2 \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks. We haven't used that notation in my course but I'll definitely be making a note of it.

Answer (score 2):

First one is correct, but unnecessarily long. I prefer $$\{n\in\Bbb Z\mid n\geq 0 \text{ and $5$ divides $n$}\}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\{n\in\Bbb N\mid \text{$5$ divides $n$}\},$$ assuming $\Bbb N$ does not contain the zero. You can further abbreviate $5\mid n$ for "$5$ divides $n$" but it looked strange in combination with the first $\mid$.

And as T. Linnell stated, your second version is not correct.

Comment: Thanks! I was going to use N, but because it said "positive integers", I thought I'd play it safe by putting in Z.

Comment: @user411697 Just be cautious with $\Bbb N$ because it is not consistently used with or without zero.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that with your second notation you might like to mean this:
$$\{x\vert x\in \mathbb{Z}, x>0, x=5\lfloor x/5\rfloor\}$$

$\lfloor a\rfloor$ is the integer part of $a$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$, that is the unique integer such that $\lfloor a\rfloor\le a<\lfloor a\rfloor+1$

Sometimes, the fractional part is represented as $\{a\} = a-\lfloor a\rfloor$, so you set can also be written thus:
$$\{x\vert x\in \mathbb{Z}, x>0, \{x/5\}=0\}$$